# ROS Network configuration on multiple machines - Publisher and Subsciber

Tags: ros

I am trying to set up a simple and listener talker across two machines connected on the same wifi network.
Machine A has the 10.42.0.89 address and is running the roscore and another node that publishes messages on a topic.

```
$ printenv | grep ROS
ROS_IP=10.42.0.89
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.89:11311
```

The other Machine B has the ROS_MASTER_URI set to match the one of machine A

```
$ printenv | grep ROS
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.89:11311
```

Machine B can get the list of available topics and running nodes correctly

```
$ rostopic list
/pose/estimate
```

But can't print out messages in that topic using `rostopic echo /pose/estimate`.

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I solved my problem by adding both machines' hostname to /etc/hosts. refer to https://husarion.com/tutorials/ros-tutorials/5-running-ros-on-multiple-machines/

Answer (score 1):

### ROS1

Machine1 [MASTER]:

- Will run `roscore`, but don't run it yet till configurations are done.
- Has an IP of `192.168.1.10`.

1- Run the following in the terminal:

1.1- `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.10:11311`.

1.2- `export ROS_IP=192.168.1.10`.

2- Now, run `roscore`.

Machine2 [SLAVE]

- Will NOT run `roscore`.
- Has and IP `192.168.1.15`.

1- Run the following in the terminal:

1.1- `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.10:11311`.

1.2- `export ROS_IP=192.168.1.15`.

2- Now, you are connected to the Master.

More information in the ROS 1 [NetworkSetup guide](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup)

---

### ROS2

ROS2 will populate the information on the LAN out of the box without any configuration.

By default you'll want to make sure [multicast is enabled](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/Installation-Troubleshooting.html?highlight=multicast)